# Nested While Loop with mysql_fetch_array is giving blank results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, nested-loops

I have used following code, Please solve any error if exist

I am trying to catch Category name from category table using parentID from Subcategory table

here is the code

```
$query_select = "SELECT * FROM subcategory where parentID<>0 and isDisabled=0 and isDeleted=0";
$result_select = mysql_query($query_select) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
  $rows[] = $row;

foreach($rows as $row){ 
  $id = $row['subcatID'];
  $subname = $row['subcatName'];
  $parentID= $row['parentID'];
  $status = $row['isDisabled'];
  $catname="";
  echo "<tr><td style='display:none;'>$id</td>";
  echo "<td><center>$subname</center></td>";
  $resultnew=mysql_query("select catName from category where catID=$parentID");

  while(mysql_fetch_row($resultnew)){
    $catname = $resultnew[0];
    echo "<script>alert($catname);</script>";
    echo "<td class='center'><center>$catname</center></td>";
  }
  if($status==0)
    {
      echo "<td class='center'><center><span class='label label-success'>Active</span></center></td>";
    }else{
    echo "<td class='center'><center><span class='label label-important'>Disabled</span></center></td>";
  }
  echo "<td class='center'><center>";
  echo "<a class='btn btn-success' href='#'><i class='icon-zoom-in icon-white'></i>View</a>";
  echo "<a class='btn btn-info' href='#'><i class='icon-edit icon-white'></i>Edit</a>";
  echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='#'><i class='icon-trash icon-white'></i>Delete</a>";
  echo "</center></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Please note that mysql_* functions are deprecated, unsafe, and should not be used. Consider using mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Comment: Well resuse of `$row` in two different contexts isn't going to help; use `$oldRow` and `$newRow` or similar to make the logic clearer

Comment: dot re-use $row, try while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
foreach($row as $row1){  instead of while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
$rows[] = $row;
foreach($rows as $row){

Comment: In your inner `while` loop, you're not assigning the result of `mysql_fetch_row($resultnew)` to anything. The next line then uses `$resultnew` as if it were the returned row.

Comment: You shouldn't use nested queries at all, you should do a LEFT JOIN between the `categories` and `subcategories` table, to get everything in one query.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys 4 your help and 4 your time...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
  while(mysql_fetch_row($resultnew)){
    $catname = $resultnew[0];
    echo "<script>alert($catname);</script>";
    echo "<td class='center'><center>select catName from category where catID=$parentID $catname</center></td>";
  }
```

to:

```
  while($newrow = mysql_fetch_row($resultnew)){
    $catname = $newrow[0];
    echo "<script>alert($catname);</script>";
    echo "<td class='center'><center>select catName from category where catID=$parentID $catname</center></td>";
  }
```

However, I presume `catID` is a unique key, so this query can only return one row, so there's no need for a while loop at all. Just write:

```
if ($newrow = mysql_fetch_row($resultnew)) {
    $catname = $newrow[0];
    echo "<script>alert($catname);</script>";
    echo "<td class='center'><center>select catName from category where catID=$parentID $catname</center></td>";
  }
```

But you can also combine this with your main query, so you don't need to do multiple queries:

```
SELECT s.subcatID, s.subcatName, s.parentID, s.isDisabled, c.catName
FROM subcategory s
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.catID = s.parentID
WHERE s.parentID <> 0 and s.isDisabled = 0 and s.isDeleted = 0
```